# Cannot resume a suspended process in background

Tags: server, ssh, suspend, process, minecraft

I'm operating a minecraft server through SSH to my server. I launched server in foreground with ssh and i would like to switch it to background. I'm currently using ubuntu version 19.04 preview. Someone said that i could press Ctrl + A + D, but it didn't work for me.

I want to continue process as background. So i tried pressing ctrl + z and calling

bg [job number]

(fg [number] worked.)

I want to make the process background and access the console without ssh (in terminal). Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start screen to use Ctrl+A+D combination.

So for short:

```
screen <your_command_to_strart_service>
```

...

use your console

press Ctrt+A+D (screen detaches)

...

And when needed back:

```
screen -r
```

(screen resumes)

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/screen.1.html for screen program uses.

To install screen in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install screen
```